# how to add a simple button that will inject a tag into a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I want to create a simple button that will inject a [b][/b] into a textarea.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is tagged jQuery, so I assume you're using it:

HTML:

```
<button id="mybutton>Bold</button>
<textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
$('mybutton').click(function(){
    $('#mytextarea').append('[b][/b]');
});
```

Of course, a real BBCode implementation with the ability to surround highlighted text with [b] tags, and/or append [b] upon the first click of the button and [/b] upon the second, is another problem entirely.

Comment: You can check out this link on solutions for getting selected text from a textarea.

http://corpocrat.com/2008/08/10/how-to-get-selected-value-in-textarea-using-javascript/